# What resolve is doing in this situation?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

New to ember, I am having trouble making sense of this code:

On the front-end, is a simple form, that is used to submit user text input as feedback

```
      <Form @onSubmit={{perform this.submitFeedback}}>

          <TextField
            @multiline={{3}}
            @placeholder="Additional comments"
            @autoFocus={{not @shouldRenderOptions}}
            @value={{this.feedbackText}}
            @disabled={{this.submitFeedback.isRunning}}
            @onChange={{action (mut this.feedbackText)}}
          />

          <ButtonGroup>
            <Button
              @text="Send feedback"
              @loading={{this.submitFeedback.isRunning}}
              @onClick={{perform this.submitFeedback}}
            />

            <Button
              @text="Cancel"
              @plain={{true}}
              @onClick={{action @onCancel}}
            />
          </ButtonGroup>
      </Form>
```

Backing it up, on the `.js` Component I have:

```
export default class FeedbackFormComponent extends Component {
  /**
   * Callback when the feedback form is submitted
   * Provides `feedbackText` and `wasContentUseful`
   * as arguments.
   *
   * @type {Function}
   * @public
   */
  onSubmitFeedback = resolve;

  @dropTask
  submitFeedback = function* submitFeedback() {
    let { feedbackText, wasContentUseful, onSubmitFeedback } = this;
    yield onSubmitFeedback(wasContentUseful, feedbackText);
  };

}
```

How can I track, what this submission is actually doing? What is `resolve` doing in a situation like this? `onSubmitFeedback = resolve;`

Comment: From where is `resolve` imported? There is probably a `import` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that is referencing a function that acts like [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve), according to the [documentation](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/rsvp/resolve).

The referenced function has this signature, where it also takes in 2 arguments like `onSubmitFeedback` does:

`resolve (value, label)`